# Rails view_paths shared across request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, actioncontroller

We are having a problem with the Rails ActionController::Base.view_paths. We are running a multi-tenant application and allow different themes for each tenant. now we have the problem that the theme view_paths dont reset on every request but stack up whenever we use prepend_view_path in the controller.

```
@paths=
  [
   ...
   @path="/app/themes/theme2/views",
   ...
   @path="/app/themes/theme1/views",
  ]
```

we are using

```
 ActionController::Base.prepend_view_path "app/themes/#{Theme.current}/views/"
```

in the controller.

Do you have an idea how we can force rails to generate view_paths new on every request?

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem.

We used ApplicationController.renderer in a service class (outside of the controller). Manipulating the `ApplicationController.view_paths` **outside** the ApplicationController forced Rails to carry the view_path over to the next request.